# Eclipse and Android excessive ram usage

Tags: android, eclipse

Yesterday I had no problem with Eclipse and Android but things went mad.

http://pastebin.com/uKrCt8ee when trying to build it.

In the end:

[2011-05-01 16:19:15 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Java heap space

[2011-05-01 16:19:15 - SiNavy] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space

Eclipse takes ~500 MB in Task Manager and it's pretty unworkable.

I've tried cleaning project, did nothing.

Any idea ?

Update: I've renamed the old project, then i've created a new one and copied the source files. Right now it should work.

Comment: May be you can fix this problem by increasing java heap space. see link http://yekmer.posterous.com/2008/07/how-to-solve-eclipse-out-of-memory.html may be it helps you.

Comment: well i've tried that, the memory increased when things I've pasted are showing (pastebin link). This is an usual problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem went away, after I created a new project and copied files from old project to the new one.

Comment: What are you trying to say.. You created a new project and it started working.

Comment: yep, then i've moved the source files: manifest, main class, layout etc and then I had no problem ;)